# Is it possible to create a two column layout using vanilla HTML/CSS with a single DIV?

Tags: html, css

I'm hoping to build a two column layout that will be utilized by a WYSIWYG editor. Example: http://taurean.io/labs/clearcut-theme/essay.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS3 **column-count** property for this. Write like this below:

```
div{
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
```

Read this for more http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

Comment: `column-count: ;` should be `column-count: 2;`

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping for but for some reason couldn't find. Every other answer was outdated, thanks.